# Finding a distribution of a random variable generated using a Monte Carlo method

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, monte-carlo

I would greatly appreciate if somebody could confirm or negate my result to the following problem. I am especially not sure about "putting it all together" step.

> 1. Generate $U_1,U_2,U_3 \sim U[0,1]$, i.i.d
> 2. If $U_1 > \frac{e}{\alpha+e}$, go to 4
> 3. Let $Y=U_2^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}.$ If $U_3 > e^{-Y}$ go to 1, else go to 5.
> 4. Let $Y=1-\log{U_2}$. If $U_3>Y^{\alpha-1}$ go to 1.
> 5. Return X=Y
>
> Find the distribution of $X$.

And this is my solution:

**Route 1.**

$\mathbb{P}(U_1>\frac{e}{\alpha+e})=\frac{a}{\alpha+e}$

$Y=1-\log{U_2} \text{ (change of variables)} \implies f_Y(y)=e^{1-y} \mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty)}(y)$

$\mathbb{P}({U_3\leq Y^{\alpha-1}})=\mathbb{P}({U_3\leq (1-\log{U_2})^{\alpha-1}})=\mathbb{E}[(1-\log{U_2})^{\alpha-1}]=\mathbb{E}[Y^{\alpha-1}]=e\Gamma(\alpha,1)$

**Route 2.**

$\mathbb{P}(U_1\leq\frac{e}{\alpha+e})=\frac{e}{\alpha+e}$

$Y=U_2^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \text{ (change of variables)} \implies f_Y(y)=\alpha y^{\alpha-1}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(y)$

$\mathbb{P}(U_3\leq e^{{U_2}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}) = \mathbb{E}[e^{{U_2}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}]$=$\displaystyle  \alpha \int_0^1 e^{-y}y^{\alpha-1}\;dy=\alpha \gamma(\alpha,1)$

Where $\Gamma(\alpha,1):=\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty}y^{\alpha-1}e^{-y}\;dy$; $\gamma(\alpha,1):=\displaystyle \int_0^1 y^{\alpha-1}e^{-y}\;dy$

**Putting it all together:**

$$f_X(y)=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+e}\Big[ e\Gamma(\alpha,1)e^{1-y} \mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty)}(y) +(1-e\Gamma(\alpha,1))f_X(y)\Big]+$$
$$+\frac{e}{\alpha+e}\Big[ \alpha \gamma(\alpha,1) \alpha y^{\alpha-1}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(y) +(1-\alpha \gamma(\alpha,1)f_X(y)\Big]$$

And the final answer:

$$f_X(y)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha,1)e^{1-y} \mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty)}(y)+ \gamma(\alpha,1) \alpha y^{\alpha-1}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(y)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$$

*Some analysis of the answer*: Good thing - it integrates to 1. Bad thing - I was expecting Gamma distribution.

Here's a scatter plot of X (from the algorithm), $\alpha=0.4$:
[image: scatter plot of X]

And of Gamma[0.4,1]:

[image: scatter plot of Gamma[a,1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us compare the probabilities of the possible outputs of one run of the algorithm:

- The path 1.-2.-3.-5. produces $X=U_2^{1/\alpha}$ and has probability $\frac{\mathrm e}{\alpha+\mathrm e}$ (for the step 2.-3.) times $\mathrm e^{-X}$ (for the step 3.-5.) of happening.
- The path 1.-2.-4.-5. produces $X=1-\log U_2$ and has probability $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\mathrm e}$ (for the step 2.-4.) times $X^{\alpha-1}$ (for the step 4.-5.) of happening.
- All the other paths go back to 1.

Since the runs are i.i.d., this shows that after a geometrically distributed number of unsuccessful runs (whose number is irrelevant), the successful run will produce a result $X$ whose density is proportional to the function $g$ such that
$$
g(x)=\frac{\mathrm e}{\alpha+\mathrm e}\cdot\mathrm e^{-x}\cdot f_1(x)+\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\mathrm e}\cdot x^{\alpha-1}\cdot f_2(x),
$$
where $f_1$ is the density of $U_2^{1/\alpha}$ and $f_2$ is the density of $1-\log U_2$. Standard computations yield
$$
f_1(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}[0\lt x\leqslant1],\qquad
f_2(x)=\mathrm e^{1-x}[x\gt1].
$$
Hence $g(x)=\frac{\alpha\mathrm e}{\alpha+\mathrm e} x^{\alpha-1}\mathrm e^{-x}[x\gt0]$, which is proportional to the density of a gamma random variable of parameter $\alpha$, that is,  $\Gamma(\alpha)^{-1}x^{\alpha-1}\mathrm e^{-x}[x\gt0]$. Finally, the distribution of $X$ is gamma with parameter $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer. I can see where I went wrong. I put $\mathbb{P}(U_3\leq e^{{U_2}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}})$ (=$e\Gamma(\alpha,1)$) instead of $x^{a-1}$. This is the step I am not sure about.

Answer (score 0):

This Mathematica 7 code was used for generation of the plots. I include this for completion.

```
b = Range[1000];
a = 0.4;
For[i = 1, i <= 1000, i++,
 X = 0;
 While[X == 0,
   U1 = RandomReal[];
   U2 = RandomReal[];
   U3 = RandomReal[];
   If[U1 > E/(E + a),
    Y = 1 - Log[U2];
    If[U3 <= Y^{a + 1}, X = Y],        
    Y = (U2)^(1/a);
    If[U3 <= Exp[Y], X = Y]
    ] 
   ]
  i;
 b[[i]] = X
 ]
ListPlot[b]
ListPlot[RandomReal[GammaDistribution[a, 1], 1000]]
```